# Where are the gcov symbols in android GCC?

Tags: android, undefined-reference, gcov

I'm trying to compile an android .so file with gcov and getting the following link errors:
in function global constructors keyed to 0_XXX:../../source/file1.cpp:2661: error: undefined reference to '__gcov_init'
in function .LPBX0:file1.cpp(.data.rel+0x24): error: undefined reference to '__gcov_merge_add' 
in function global constructors keyed to 0_funcname:../../source/file2.cpp:2154: error: undefined reference to '__gcov_init'
in function .LPBX0:file2.cpp(.data.rel+0x24): error: undefined reference to '__gcov_merge_add'
'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [xxx.so] Error 1

My android makefile change: CFLAGS += --coverage, LOCAL_LDLIBS += --coverage.
I can't seem to find the location of the missing symbols. My android toolchain gcc version 4.6.
Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may add following lines to the Android.mk:

LOCAL_CFLAGS  += -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage

LOCAL_LDFLAGS += -lgcov

Comment: Ray, thanks for your reply. I've tried that way, but still encountered "undefined reference to '__gcov_init' and '__gcov_merge_add' issue".  I searched the whole android source code and find libgcov.a in several folders. I also tried LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARY += libgcov, another error showed "out/target/product/XXX/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libgcov_intermediates/libgcov.a(_gcov.o): in function gcov_version(,text+0x98): error: undefined reference to '_impure_ptr'". Do you know about this?

Answer (score 0):

change the Android.mk with these 3 lines

1) **LOCAL_LDLIBS += -l(absolutepath or relativepath to libgcov)**

for eg:
LOCAL_LDLIBS += -l/home/souradeep.c/JFLTEATT/android/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-eabi-4.6/lib/gcc/arm-eabi/4.6.x-google/libgcov.a

2) **LOCAL_LDFLAGS += -fprofile-arcs**    (this is needed for linking important for ur symbol not found problem)

3) **LOCAL_CFLAGS += -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage**

```
                   or
```

3) **LOCAL_CPPFLAGS += -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage**

Enjoy.......................................